# Not able to bring Bitbucket repo to azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket

I have generated the app password and took the clone URL correctly, although azure devops seems to be not recognizing. Please help , below are the screenshots with error

[image]

[image]

Comment: That should do it. If it doesn't you can always manually mirror the repo from your commandline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue:

[image]

1. To clone a repository, the app password should at least have
   **Repositories -> Read premission:**

   [image]
2. When importing the repository, **the username should be your account
   name rather than app password name**.

   [image]

Comment: I am trying as described in your answer but I am not able to do it

Comment: Everyone needs to upvote this answer. I was genuinely stuck using the "label" as the username. Thanks a lot.